# Cordova Windows Phone 8 not receiving notifications (working on other platforms)

Tags: cordova, azure, windows-phone-8, push-notification, phonegap-pushplugin

My app is in Cordova and meant to run on 3 platforms: Android, Windows and Ios.
On Android the device is registering, sending and receiving notifications. IOs has not been tested yet. On windows phone I can send notifications but cant receive.

I will split the question in parts to explain myself better.

When I open the cross platform solution and try to run from:
a) Windows Phone - I get 'Bootstrapper could not connect to the machine'
b) Windows Phone Universal - I get an error that alert is undefined. Now since we're using Cordova this just does not make sense. I mean we're using Javascript to be able to run cross platform.
c) Windows Phone 8 - it simply does not run. Gives me this warning:

Warning CS4014  Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call. NativeExecution.cs

I decided to try to run the program from the specific platform folder i.e. the platforms/WP8 directory: I am able to send push notifications from my app but not able to receive them.

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
mobileServiceClient = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient(
                'https://----------.azure-mobile.net/',
                '------------------------------');

// Create a pushNotification (from the PushPlugin).
pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;

alert(device.platform);

//Platform-specific registrations.
//Here goes Android and IOs registrations

if (device.platform == "Win32NT") {
    var channelName = device.uuid;
    alert(device.uuid);

    pushNotification.register(
        channelHandler,
        errorHandlerWP8,
        {
            "channelName": channelName,
            "ecb": "onNotificationWP8",
            "uccb": "channelHandler",
            "errcb": "jsonErrorHandler"
        });
}
});
```

So when the app starts it successfully enters the above 'addeventlistener' and shows the 'device.uuid' alert as supposed to. From then on, it register with the channelHandler method:

```
function channelHandler(result) {
    alert('registered### 1' + JSON.stringify(result));
}
```

When I send notifications to the same azure service from a difference device, I receive the notification from Android and Windows 8 devices (not windows phone 8) (which are registered to the same service) but not from the Windows phone device. It is like the notification is never making its way into the device in the first place.

The: alert(device.platform) is not fired. The device(uuid) is not fired. The OnNotification(WP8) method is obviously then not reached.

Finally, I figured since the notification is most likely not even making its way in the device, there could be something wrong in the insert.js methods of the todoitem script of Azure. However note, that on a windows app which I have created and registered to the same service, I am successfully receiving notifications with the payloads below. Below is the insert.js method of the todoitem of Azure:

```
function insert(item, user, request) {
    request.execute({
        success: function () {
            var payload = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><toast><visual>' +
    '<binding template="ToastText01">  <text id="1">' +
    item.text + '</text></binding></visual></toast>';
        // If the insert succeeds, send a notification.
        push.wns.send(null, payload, 'wns/toast', {
            success: function (pushResponse) {
                console.log("Sent push:", pushResponse);
                request.respond();
            },
            error: function (pushResponse) {
                console.log("Error Sending push:", pushResponse);
                request.respond(500, { error: pushResponse });
            }
        });

        //Define a payload for Android 

        var Androidpayload = '{ "message" : "Notification: ' + item.text + '" }';

        push.send(null, Androidpayload, {
            success: function (pushResponse) {
                console.log("Sent push:", pushResponse);
                 //Send the default response.
                request.respond();
            },
            error: function (pushResponse) {
                console.log("Error Sending push:", pushResponse);
                 //Send the error response.
                request.respond(500, { error: pushResponse });
            }
        });
    }
});
}
```

I have run out of ideas of what the problem could be. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: This plugin is now deprecated. Have you used [phonegap-plugin-push](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push)?

Comment: Hey. Yes, I started using the new plugin but I still can't make it work on Windows. I have recently also tested on IOS and I am also only managing to register, but not receive notifications. Nothing happens when a notification is supposedly making its way into the device. May I also add that upon following this tutorial from Microsoft: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-windows-store-dotnet-get-started/#overview I am registering on both Windows store apps and windows phone platforms but only receiving notifications from windows store apps